# Caret before link

Tags: html, css

Is possible to place a caret before a html link without using a list ?
I do have a working code for lists but of course it doesn't work for single links:

```
.list-caret {
  margin: 0.75em 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-caret li:before {
  content: "";
  border-color: transparent #ec6608;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -0.8em;
  top: 1.1em;
  color: #ec6608;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: [Why don't you use a  unicode character](https://jsfiddle.net/y9mjte2k/)?

Comment: What Vucko said. Also, as far as I can tell, all you need to do is apply your second rule to `a` as well? Like `a.list-caret::before`. Maybe you should add some HTML markup and make your code into a Stack Snippet so it is easier for us to know what's going on.

Comment: Also, for your list, you might want to look into [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) - although, to be fair, setting a string for this seems to only work in FF at the moment. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the job:

```css
a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  border-color: transparent #ec6608;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -10px;
  top: 1.1em;
  color: #ec6608;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a link with a caret before on it</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:before` with anchor tag and add `display: inline-block;` to anchor

```css
.list-caret {
  margin: 0.75em 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-caret li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-caret li a:before {
  content: " ";
  border-color: transparent #ec6608;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -0.8em;
  top: 1.1em;
  color: #ec6608;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-caret">
  <li><a href="javascript:;">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```